# AddSingleton with async Invoke?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-core, singleton, .net-core

I add a singleton like this.

In Startup.cs, I add the following:

```
services.AddSingleton<MySingleton>();
```

I want to build my singleton like this (which is not possible of course):

```
public class MySingleton
{
    public MySingleton()
    {
        await InitAsync();
    }

    private async Task InitAsync()
    {
        await Stuff();
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem without creating deadlocks?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I can tell, configuration in ASP.NET Core is not asynchronous, so there is no way to add a service with async factory, or anything like that.

Because of that and considering that blocking is not a big issue if it's only done once when application starts, I think you should block when creating the service. And since ASP.NET Core does not have a synchronization context, this will also not cause a deadlock.

Comment: Blazor for example does not allow blocking

Answer (score 1):

This question is legitimate, but I haven't seen a proper answer. In order to achieve it you will have to follow the next steps:

1. Hide the constructor.
2. Add new public async method to asynchronously return a new instance of your service class.
3. Add in this new asynchronous method the async logic you would like to execute when instantiating your service.

Therefore, modify your service class as follows:

```
public class MySingleton
{
    private MySingleton(/*Parameters you need*/)
    {
      /*Initialize this instance from your parameters*/
    }

    public async Task<MySingleton> CreateAsync(/*Parameters you need and more, even factories with async methods*/)
    {
        /*Call your constructor*/
        var lMySingelton = MySingleton(/*Parameters you need*/);

        /*Do everything you want async related with with your new MySingleton instance*/
        await InitAsync();

        /*return your new MySingleton instance*/
        return lMySingelton ;
    }

    public static async Task InitAsync()
    {
        await Stuff();
    }
}
```

Finally modify your main as async and slightly modify the way you would usually inject your dependency as follows:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] lArgs)
{
   var lBuilder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(lArgs);
   lBuilder.Services.AddSingleton(await MySingleton.CreateAsync(/*Parameters is you need*/));
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good example. If you need to perform any async initialisation, I would instead implement an `IHostedService`, then you can ensure that your startup code runs when the host starts, using any other DI dependencies.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Yes but that's different topic as far as this thread is about "AddSingleton with async Invoke?" and the author did not specify why needed that.

Comment: But your example can't have any other dependencies from DI.

Comment: You can add as many dependencies you want to inject by CreateAsync parameters as in my example CreateAsync emulates an async constructor :)

Comment: Sure, you can pass parameters to `.CreateAsync`. But what about some `IOptions<T>`, which is configured by some other service... Nope, because you are creating the instance of the singleton *before* building the host, before the `IServiceProvider` has been created. As I said, if your singleton needs a dependency from your DI container, your approach wont work. But an `IHostedService` can use any DI defined dependency.

Comment: You can just not inject from the host DI container, dependency injection is a pattern and IServiceProvider just uses this pattern. This does not disable using DI, just using it from the ASP.NET dependency container. Still my solution answers the question presented in this post with this tradeoff you are pointing now, which I think brings value because it's something to have into account. I would love you to make a formal reply with your purpose solving the topic of this post so people can have more options available. The more options to choose from the better!

Answer (score 0):

Can you use construct it normally, and use it async and allow your async initialization to happen lazily when needed?

```
public class MySingleton {
   private bool initialized=false;
   private SemaphoreSlim mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
   public async Task DoStuff() {
       if (!initialized) {
           await mutex.WaitAsync();
           try {
               if (!initialized) {
                   await InitAsync();
                   initialized = true;
               }
           } finally {
               mutex.Release();
           }
       }
       DoTheRealStuff();
   }
   private async Task InitAsync() {
       await Stuff();
   }
}
```

Comment: You can't `await` inside a `lock`.

Comment: @svick, you are totally right, I forgot.  I updated my example  to use a SemaphoreSlim as a mutex instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading/) NuGet package and then design your class like this:

```
public class Singleton {

  private static readonly AsyncLazy<Singleton> instance =
      new AsyncLazy<Singleton>( CreateAndDoSomething );

  private Singleton() {
  }

  // This method could also be an async lambda passed to the AsyncLazy constructor.
  private static async Task<Singleton> CreateAndDoSomething() {
     var ret = new Singleton();
     await ret.InitAsync();
     return ret;
  }

  private async Task InitAsync() {
     await Stuff();
  }

  public static AsyncLazy<Singleton> Instance
  {
     get { return instance; }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
Singleton singleton = Singleton.Instance;
```

More on [Asynchronous Lazy Initialization](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/asynchronous-lazy-initialization.html).

Comment: Will this work with `AddSingleton` from ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection? Because that's what the question is about.

Comment: Also, `Instance` returns `AsyncLazy<Singleton>`, not `Singleton`. Did you forget `await` in your usage?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem that you are facing is that constructors can't have async modifiers. If that is the case, you can do the following. If not, please elaborate.

```
    public MySingleton()
    {
        InitAsync().Wait();
    }
```

The other thing you can explore is try to use the Double Check Lock Pattern (DCLP). If will be like below -

```
private volatile object _sync = new Object();

if (!_init) 
{
    lock (_sync) 
    { 
        if (!_init) 
        { 
        }
     }
}
```

This is supported in C#/.Net. You should find more references to this on the interwebs.

Comment: How does DCLP help here?

Comment: Honeslty, idk. But, i just threw it in there for the following reasons. 

1. DCLP is a common pattern to initialize singletons. 
2. It gives greater flexibility to use the async pattern. 
3. Doing a lot of things in the constructor is frowned upon. i.e. calling InitAsync().